# WebClient maxConnection pool limit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

How many concurrent requests can I send if the remote service if blocking?
Means: what is the *maxConnection* pool limit that spring uses internally when using `WebClient`?

```
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;

webClient.post().uri(url).syncBody(req).retrieve().bodyToMono(type);
```

And moreover: how can I modify it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before reactor-netty 0.9.0.M4 version there wasn't limit by default because of "elastic" connection provider was used. [This fix](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/578) changed it to "fixed" connection provider with the limit of 500.

To change the connection pool limit you could define your own `WebClient.Builder` bean and use it to create `WebClient`

```
@Bean
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
    String connectionProviderName = "myConnectionProvider";
    int maxConnections = 100;
    int acquireTimeout = 1000;
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider
            .fixed(connectionProviderName, maxConnections, acquireTimeout));
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient));
}
```

Or you could implement custom `org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientCustomizer` in the same manner with the predefined `WebClient.Builder`

Answer (score 3):

taken from the netty [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_connection_pool)

> By default, the TCP client uses a “fixed” connection pool with 500 as
>   the maximum number of the channels and 45s as the acquisition timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
Notice that only the default HttpClient (HttpClient.create()) uses 500 as the maximum number of active channels. In the example above, when instantiating a custom ConnectionProvider, we are changing this value to 50 using maxConnections. Also, if you don’t set this parameter the default maxConnections is used (2 * available number of processors).
```

If we configure custom `ConnectionProvider`, the default will be `(2 * available number of processors)` from the netty [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_connection_pool_2)